# Carousel and self.root code problem. I am developing an Application using Python Kivy. My code closes after clicking the button

Tags: python, button, kivy, carousel, kivymd

The code closes after clicking the first proceed when it is supposed to continue to the next page and can click the procceed button again, it should 4 times after clicking the Proceed button again. When I tried not to compile the code with other kivy files, it runs very well and accurate but when I try to compiled it again, it closes right away after clicking the Proceed button, the carousel itself is working but also in only one slide. It's not continue going to the next page. I have try to add and change the code but it shows the same error. Can someone please help me.

Here is the entire code fot python file:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivymd.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.utils import rgba
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
Window.size = (310, 580)\`

class Scrolling(ScrollView):
pass

class OnBoarding(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def build(self):
        global screen_manager
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("one.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("two.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("three.kv"))
        self.root = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        return screen_manager
    
    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.change_screen, 5)
    
    def change_screen(self,dt):
        screen_manager.current = "two"
    
    def current_slide(self, index):
        for i in range(4):
            if index != i:
                self.root.ids[f"slide{i}"].color = rgba(131, 173, 97)
            else:
                self.root.ids[f"slide{i}"].color = rgba(79, 121, 47)
    
    def next(self):
        self.root.ids.carousel.load_next(mode="next")

if __name__ == '__main__':
OnBoarding().run()
```

Here is the kv file:

```
MDScreen:
    name:"main"
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color:1, 1, 1, 1
        Image:
            source:"background.png"
            size_hint: .7, .7
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .65}
    MDFloatLayout:
        id: parent_widget
        md_bg_color:1, 1, 1, 1
        Carousel:
            id: carousel
            on_current_slide: app.current_slide(self.index)
            MDFloatLayout:
                Image:
                    source:"first.png"
                    size_hint: .8, .9
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .70}
                MDLabel:
                    text: "First Page"
                    font_size: "20sp"
                    pos_hint: {"center_y": .45}
                    color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 255)
                MDLabel:
                    text: "First Definition"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .37}
                    size_hint_x: .85
                    color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 255)
            MDFloatLayout:
                Image:
                    source:"second.png"
                    size_hint: .8, .8
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .70}
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Second Page"
                    pos_hint: {"center_y": .45}
                    halign: "center"
                    color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 255)
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Second Definition"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .37}
                    size_hint_x: .85
                    color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 255)
        Button:
            text: "Proceed"
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            font_size: "18sp"
            size_hint: .8, .070
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .2}
            border: 0, 32, 0, 32
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: rgba(79, 121, 47)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [20]
            on_release:
                app.next()
        MDLabel:
            id: slide0
            text: "."
            halign: "center"
            font_size: "80sp"
            color: rgba(79, 121, 47)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .40, "center_y": .31}
        MDLabel:
            id: slide1
            text: "."
            halign: "center"
            font_size: "80sp"
            color: rgba(131,173,97)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .47, "center_y": .31}
        MDLabel:
            id: slide2
            text: "."
            halign: "center"
            font_size: "80sp"
            color: rgba(131,173,97)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .55, "center_y": .31}
```

The code closes after clicking the first proceed when it is supposed to continue to the next page and can click the procceed button again, it should 4 times after clicking the Proceed button again. When I tried not to compile the code with other kivy files, it runs very well and accurate but when I try to compiled it again, it closes right away after clicking the Proceed button, the carousel itself is working but also in only one slide. It's not continue going to the next page. I have try to add and change the code but it shows the same error. Can someone please help me.

Comment: You need to correctly format your `kv` file.

Comment: There I edited it, that is the original format of my KV file. It still not working, it still has the same error.

Comment: Noted. Thanks, I trimmed it already. I hope someone knows what the solution is. I really need help regarding this.

Comment: it seems like you don't have all of the kivy files or content there.  If possible it is easist if you use builder.load_string(''' ''') and put all of your content inside the string, that way your example is a single wall of runnable text in a single .py file.

Answer (score 0):

1. You did not add `Builder.load_file("main.kv")` to ScreenManager object. Replace `self.root = Builder.load_file("main.kv")` with `screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("main.kv"))`
2. You did not provided `one.kv`, `two.kv` and `three.kv` content
3. Replace all occurences of `self.root.ids` with `self.root.get_screen('main').ids`
4. You don't have any Screen with name `"two"` specified within `change_screen` method which is invoked after 5 seconds from start.
5. You are trying to set `color` attribute within loop `for i in range(4):` for `ids[slide3]` `ids[f"slide{i}"]` while there is no widget with `id: slide3` within your `main.kv`

Fix your code, and post console output if you want to get quality help.